# Error 403 from post request using UrlFetchApp, same parameters work from curl

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-status-code-403

I am getting a 403 error while attempting a post request using the following code:

```
var URL = 'https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Ancestor';
  
var options =
{
  "method" : "post",
  "contentType" : "application/json",
  "payload" : '{"query":{"status":{"option":"online"},"type":"Tainted Chaos Orb","stats":[{"type":"and","filters":[]}]},"sort":{"price":"asc"}}'
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options);
```

The same post parameters work just fine using an API tester website:
[text](https://reqbin.com/zy0aeyys)

The following curl works just fine from cmd:

```
curl -X POST https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Ancestor -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"query\":{\"status\":{\"option\":\"online\"},\"type\":\"Tainted Chaos Orb\",\"stats\":[{\"type\":\"and\",\"filters\":[]}]},\"sort\":{\"price\":\"asc\"}}"
```

I am not sure what is causing the problem. I suspect the API is blocking requests from google. Is there any way around this? I want to import some data into my google sheets.

Comment: I think yes, Pathofexile is blocking requests from Google sheets

Comment: `The same post parameters work just fine using an API tester website` Are you sure about that? Returned "Cannot process your request."

Comment: Try adding `Accept` header.

Comment: Not sure why reqbin is giving "Cannot process your request." error now. It was working fine when I posted. Strange.

I tried adding"Accept" : "*/*" to headers, did not help. Still error 403.

If indeed pathofexile is blocking google, is there any clever way around it? SO that I can import data to google sheets?